# Dumbledore's joke - how does it end?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

There's a joke Dumbledore never finishes in The Goblet of Fire:

> "I am *not* joking, Mr. Weasley," he said, "though now that you mention it, I did hear an excellent one over the summer about a troll, a hag, and a leprechaun who all go into a bar..."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire - The Triwizard Tournament</sub>

Is a canon answer ever given as to how the joke ends?

Comment: I know this is probably Primarily Opinion Based, but can we have some fun this time?

Comment: If Rowling has provided an answer, I'd say we have one.

Comment: @fez - Fanfiction. Not a reputable answer at all.

Comment: "$20, same as in town."

Comment: Then the bartender says, *"What'll it be today, Umbridge?" :P

Comment: @marcellothearcane There is no room for fun on stack exchange. This is a place for serious business such as solving programming issues and explaining children's books to adults.

Comment: It's a metajoke, playing on the real world existence of various jokes beginning with some set of people walking into a bar. I doubt Ms. Rowling had any particular joke in mind.

Comment: @chepner yes, I know.. just wondering if people wanted to have some fun coming up with the ending (like @Bellatrix). Might not be appropriate though.

Comment: According to Professor McGonagall, it ends *badly*.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I've edited your question, so that it's no longer opinion based and is now on-topic. If you don't like how it currently stands, you can change it. But to keep it open, you'll need to keep the "is an answer given" so that the answer can be "no". :)

Comment: "... and bartender looks up and says, 'What is this? Some sort of a joke?'"

Comment: I also want to hear how the joke about the Mimbulus Mimbletonia ends.

Comment: @TheDarkLord lol yeah, I noticed that one too!

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to prove a negative, but I haven't been able to find a canon answer to this, so I believe the answer is "No" we never find out how the joke ends.

"A ---, a --- and a --- go into a bar" is a common opening line for jokes, so it seems clear that JKR simply picked a variation of the line that was appropriate for the wizarding world. If she had made up a punch line that she thought was funny, there is no reason for her not to have included it.